# Put two DIVs next to another DIV

Tags: html, css

How can I put the blue division on the right of the red & green ones?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #red {width:100px; height:50px; background:red;}
            #green {width:100px; height:50px; background:green;}
            #blue {width:100px; height:100px; background:blue;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
        <div id="blue"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know how to do it by adding another div as a parent to the first and second divisions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #parent {float:left;}
            #red {width:100px; height:50px; background:red;}
            #green {width:100px; height:50px; background:green;}
            #blue {width:100px; height:100px; background:blue; float:left;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="parent">
            <div id="red"></div>
            <div id="green"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="blue"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I wonder if I can achieve what I'm after without adding another HTML element.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you even try anything yourself? This doesn't seem like altogether a difficult thing to do....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the float attribute to make elements appear side-by-side.

UPDATE: You can achieve this effect with relative positioning, please see the demo and code below.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/Frf6w/90/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#red {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}

#green {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;

    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

#blue {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;

    top: -50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work as it puts all of them side by side. I just want the blue one to be next to the others. The red and green DIVs shouldn't re-position.

Comment: No problem, but this will only work if you know the height of the first `DIV`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
style="float:left"
```

what this does, is it makes the divs take up as much space horizontally before taking up vertical space

Comment: It doesn't work as it puts all of them side by side. I just want the blue one to be next to the others. The red and green DIVs shouldn't re-position.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#red {width:100px; height:50px; background:red;}
#parent {float: left; }
#green {width:100px; height:50px; background:green;}
#blue {width:100px; height:100px; background:blue; float: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Made some changes to it.
thing is: if u want red and green to be underneath eachother u kinda have to put them into an other division and float the other division next to it.
Can you explain why exactly u would want it without parent?

Comment: It doesn't work as it puts all of them side by side. I just want the blue one to be next to the others. The red and green DIVs shouldn't re-position.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` to all your `div`s.

Comment: It doesn't work as it puts all of them side by side. I just want the blue one to be next to the others. The red and green DIVs shouldn't re-position.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    max-width:200px;
    margin:auto;    
}
#red {width:100px; height:50px; background:red; **float:left;**}
#green {width:100px; height:50px; background:green;**float:left;**}
#blue {width:100px; height:100px; background:blue;**float:right;**}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've changed the body size to contain the 3 divs in the arrangment i think you were after.

There are lots of different methods, but this is the one I'd go for. (Doens't mean its better though)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It doesn't help. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code on the blue div:

```
style="float:left"
```